# Why does the object instance I retrieve via libloading make the program to segfault despite lifetime contraints?

Tags: rust, plugins, segmentation-fault, lifetime

I am beginning with Rust and I design a plugin mechanism based on [`libloading`](https://docs.rs/crate/libloading/latest) as learning opportunity, beside the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). I am unsure if the issue I have is due to misunderstanding with Rust or `libloading`, or if there is an issue with either. In any case, here we go...

I defined a crate composed of one library (`lib.rs`) and one binary (`bin.rs`). Both import and use a module defined in a third file `animal.rs`, via `import animal` at the top of their source.
`animal.rs` defines a single train `Animal` with a single method `speak()`, that takes no argument and returns nothing:

```
pub trait Animal
{
    fn speak(&self);
}
```

The library (`lib.rs`) provides an implementation for `Animal`, with a concrete `struct Dog`, holding a single `String`, its associated implementation and an implementation of the trait `Animal` for Dog:

```
mod animal;

struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

impl Dog {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Dog {
        Dog {
            name: name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

impl animal::Animal for Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("{}: ruff, ruff!", self.name);
    }
}
```

Finally, I add a function that takes a string, and returns a dynamic type `Animal` (via `Box<dyn animal::Animal>`). I make sure the name is not mangled so that `libloading` can find and load it:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn get_animal(name: &str) -> Box<dyn animal::Animal>
{
    Box::new(Dog::new(name))
}
```

Now, the binary `bin.rs` reuse the [`libloading` documentation example](https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/#usage). I try to wrap it into a convenient `struct Dynlib<T>`, that instanciates and holds `libloading::Library` from a filename and store the name of the function that creates and returns a new instance of an implementation of trait `T`, i.e., `Animal`. For usage convenience, I use `PhantomData` to pin the generic type to the structure definition.

```
struct Dynlib<T>
{
    lib: libloading::Library,
    symbol: String,
    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Dynlib<T>
{
    fn new(lib_file: &str, symbol: &str) -> Result<Dynlib<T>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
    {
        unsafe {
            Ok(Dynlib {
                lib: libloading::Library::new(lib_file)?,
                symbol: String::from(symbol),
                phantom: std::marker::PhantomData,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Actual instances are fetched with `Dynlib<T>::run(&self, &str)`. To make sure that instances returned can be used safely, I defined `struct Ref` to pin their lifetime to the instance of `Dynlib` used to get the new instance, since (as I understand), the lifetime of the instance returned cannot exceed the lifetime of `Dynlib<T>::lib` it comes from. For convenience, I implement trat `Deref` for `Ref`:

```
struct Ref<'a, T: 'a>{
    pub obj: T,
    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<T> std::ops::Deref for Ref<'_, T>
{
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target
    {
        &self.obj
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Ref<'a, T>
{
    fn new(obj: T) -> Ref<'a, T>
    {
        Ref{
            obj,
            phantom: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Dynlib<T>
...
    fn run<'a>(& 'a mut self, name: &str) -> Result<Ref<'a, T>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
    {
        unsafe {
            let func: libloading::Symbol::<unsafe extern fn(&str) -> T> = self.lib.get(self.symbol.as_bytes())?;
            let obj = func(name);
            Ok(Ref::<'a, T>::new(obj))
        }
    }
...
}
```

Now I expect that the Rust compiler will not let me define any variables owning any value returned by `Dynlib<T>::run(...)` to have a lifetime that exceed that of said `Dynlib instance:

```
fn main()
{
    let _b;
    {
        let mut _a = Dynlib::<Box<dyn animal::Animal>>::new("/home/debian/plugin/target/debug/libplugin.so", "get_animal").unwrap();
        _b = _a.run("Stig").unwrap();
    }
    _b.speak();
}
```

Compiling:

```
error[E0597]: `_a` does not live long enough
  --> src/bin.rs:64:14
   |
64 |         _b = _a.run("Stig").unwrap();
   |              ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
65 |     }
   |     - `_a` dropped here while still borrowed
66 |         _b.speak();
   |         -- borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `plugin`.
```

As intended. If I fix the lifetime issue:

```
fn main()
{
    {   
        let mut _a = Dynlib::<Box<dyn animal::Animal>>::new("/home/debian/plugin/target/debug/libplugin.so", "get_animal").unwrap();
        let _b = _a.run("Stig").unwrap();
        _b.speak();
    }
}
```

The not only it compile, but it runs as expected:

```
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$ cargo run
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling libloading v0.7.4
   Compiling plugin v0.1.0 (/home/debian/plugin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.22s
     Running `target/debug/pluginrun`
Stig: ruff, ruff!
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$
```

Things get more interesting when I try something like this:

```
fn main()
{
    let _b;
    {   
        let mut _a = Dynlib::<Box<dyn animal::Animal>>::new("/home/debian/plugin/target/debug/libplugin.so", "get_animal").unwrap();
        _b = _a.run("Stig").unwrap();
        _b.speak();
    }
}
```

`_b` has a larger lifetime than `_a`, so I would expect Rust to reject this code. On the other hand, `_b` is never used outside the lifetime of `_a`, so Rust might accept it after all, and everything should run smooth. TO sum up, either Rust rejects it, or it accepts it and it runs well. Turns out things happen differently:

```
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$ cargo run
   Compiling plugin v0.1.0 (/home/debian/plugin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.60s
     Running `target/debug/pluginrun`
Stig: ruff, ruff!
Segmentation fault
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$
```

Rust does accept the code, but the code fails to run, with an ugly `Segmentation fault` that Rust promised they would be near old-history told in fairy tales to scare the kids. Why is that so, and what I can do to have sufficient compile-time check to either refuse it or accept and it runs?

Here are variants of the same issue:

```
fn main()
{
    let _b;
    {   
        let mut _a = Dynlib::<Box<dyn animal::Animal>>::new("/home/debian/plugin/target/debug/libplugin.so", "get_animal").unwrap();
        _b = _a.run("Stig");
        _b.unwrap().speak();
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$ cargo run
   Compiling plugin v0.1.0 (/home/debian/plugin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.46s
     Running `target/debug/pluginrun`
Stig: ruff, ruff!
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$
```

Now that looks like what I expected, except I wish I could unwrap the result of `run()` right away and let `Ref<T>` track the lifetime for me, and I don't need to unwrap every time I need to use the instance.

More interesting:

```
fn main()
{
    {   
        let _b;
        let mut _a = Dynlib::<Box<dyn animal::Animal>>::new("/home/debian/plugin/target/debug/libplugin.so", "get_animal").unwrap();
        _b = _a.run("Stig").unwrap();
        _b.speak();
    }
}
```

```
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$ cargo run
   Compiling plugin v0.1.0 (/home/debian/plugin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.57s
     Running `target/debug/pluginrun`
Stig: ruff, ruff!
Segmentation fault
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin
```

Here again, Rust accepts some code that does not run well, although `_b` has the same lifetime as `_a`. This works:

```
fn main()
{
    {   
        let mut _a = Dynlib::<Box<dyn animal::Animal>>::new("/home/debian/plugin/target/debug/libplugin.so", "get_animal").unwrap();
        let _b;
        _b = _a.run("Stig").unwrap();
        _b.speak();
    }
}
```

```
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$ cargo run
   Compiling plugin v0.1.0 (/home/debian/plugin)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.29s
     Running `target/debug/pluginrun`
Stig: ruff, ruff!
debian@bullseyebuilder:~/plugin$
```

Although this is the same as the second example as above (the first compiling and working as expected).

My question is: what can I do to make Rust to have a reliable compile-time check of the values fetched via `libloading`? Why is the solution I have for now is only covering a subset of lifetime-related issues? Why moving `unwrap()` from a line to another changes the outcome?

Bonus points:
Is there any `struct` in Rust's standard library that can play the role of `Ref<'a, T>` shown above, i.e., pinning the instance contained to some lifetime?

"Attempted solutions" field below:
Since most details given on the problem description field, I opted to add here complete source and Cargo files

I tried Rust 1.48 ([Debian Bullseye](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/) default) and Rust 1.60 (latest on [Easybuild](https://easybuild.io/)) with the same results.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "plugin"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"]
#edition = "2022"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[lib]
crate-type=["dylib"]
name = "plugin"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[[bin]]
name="pluginrun"
path="src/bin.rs"

[dependencies]
libloading = "0.7.4"
```

`src/lib.rs`
:

```
mod animal;

struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

impl Dog {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Dog {
        Dog {
            name: name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

impl animal::Animal for Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("{}: ruff, ruff!", self.name);
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn get_animal(name: &str) -> Box<dyn animal::Animal>
{
    Box::new(Dog::new(name))
}
```

`src/animal.rs`:

```
pub trait Animal
{
    fn speak(&self);
}
```

`src/bin.rs`:

```
mod animal;

struct Ref<'a, T: 'a>{
    pub obj: T,
    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<T> std::ops::Deref for Ref<'_, T>
{
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target
    {
        &self.obj
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Ref<'a, T>
{
    fn new(obj: T) -> Ref<'a, T>
    {
        Ref{
            obj,
            phantom: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}            

struct Dynlib<T>
{
    lib: libloading::Library,
    symbol: String,
    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}


impl<T> Dynlib<T>
{
    fn new(lib_file: &str, symbol: &str) -> Result<Dynlib<T>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
    {
        unsafe {
            Ok(Dynlib {
                lib: libloading::Library::new(lib_file)?,
                symbol: String::from(symbol),
                phantom: std::marker::PhantomData,
            })
        }
    }

    fn run<'a>(& 'a mut self, name: &str) -> Result<Ref<'a, T>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
    {
        unsafe {
            let func: libloading::Symbol::<unsafe extern fn(&str) -> T> = self.lib.get(self.symbol.as_bytes())?;
            let obj = func(name);
            Ok(Ref::<'a, T>::new(obj))
        }
    }
}

fn main()
{
    {
        let mut _a = Dynlib::<Box<dyn animal::Animal>>::new("/home/debian/plugin/target/debug/libplugin.so", "get_animal").unwrap();
        let _b;
        _b = _a.run("Stig").unwrap();
        _b.speak();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you drop `_b` after the library is freed. However, because you told Rust you only have a reference to `T` (`PhantomData<&'a T>`), it thinks you don't drop it and therefore it can shrink `'a` as needed.

A way to solve that is to force Rust to consider your type as having a drop glue, by providing a dummy `Drop` impl:

```rust
impl<T> Drop for Ref<'_, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks a lot. So the lifetime annotation linking the output of `run<'a>()` to `&'a self` is not sufficient? Scary to think I will need to go that far to make sure Rust does check what I mean it to. There a long learning way ahead!

Comment: @Nykau It is not sufficient in this case because Rust may shrink the lifetime. But yes, when you write unsafe code, you need to be very very careful.

Comment: Now I cannot move my instance of `Ref`. Is there any other way to ensure lifetime checking than implementing `Drop`, so that move operations are still allowed?

Comment: @Nykau There is no way around that. If the object is considered borrowed, you cannot move it. If not, you got a UAF.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that jumps out to me is you're using different [ABI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html#abi)s between definition and loading.

```
pub fn get_animal(name: &str) -> Box<dyn animal::Animal>
```

The definition of `get_animal` has no `extern` qualifier, meaning it is using Rust's own ABI.

```
let func: Symbol::<unsafe extern fn(&str) -> T> = ...;
```

Using `extern` on the function pointer means it will use C's ABI.

Try adding `extern` to the definition or remove it from the loaded type (though if you make the function itself `extern`, the compiler may complain about your types not being FFI-safe).

---

I'm skeptical whether this will actually solve the problem though since the data and vtable pointers in `Box` work well enough to call `.speak()`, but it is wrong and should be fixed nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you for the catch. I altered the definition of `get_animal` so `pub extern fn get_animal(name: &str) -> Box<dyn animal::Animal>`. I also tried to remove the `extern` from both definition and loading. Either way, the behavior stays the same.

Comment: You cannot use dyn traits for the C ABI as their layout is not guaranteed.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Agreed, I only should've mentioned removing `extern`. I was thinking using `extern` with non-FFI-safe types between compilation units with the same compiler *should* work (these things are usually self-consistent), but I don't know if that's *guaranteed* (it probably isn't because Rust doesn't guarantee much outside of intended use-cases).